# "Connection failed" during $ sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt

when perform

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources          
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

Comment: We need more information. Do other web sites work ? are you behind a proxy? Did you try another mirror?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen is this a case of unmet dependencies? I have experienced this error in the past and it's cause? My internet was disconnected.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04, and using another sites like google, yahoo, sql, and other many sites, and yes I'm behind a proxy, and when I use this command it's trying automatically to connect with more than one mirror like , Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
 Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
or what do you mean by another mirror?

Comment: If you open the "Software and Updates" GUI, you can select which mirror you download updates from. There is a (relatively) massive list in there, and there is even a button that will automatically select the best one based on connectivity and bandwidth.

Comment: @CheddieMerai - could be any number of issues simply stating something is broken is insufficient information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are behind a proxy, edit or create the file : /etc/apt/apt.conf

And insert your proxy settings :

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>";
```

Save it, and relaunch the apt-get command